# How to fix a gap on right side of a mobile website

Tags: html, css, optimization, media-queries

I am working on a school project and am optimizing for mobile. When I go on the website, I see a white gap on the right side of the screen (see screenshot). I have tried to do research but everything I've found doesn't work. [iPhone Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQBxq.png). Could someone help guide me in the right direction? I have never made a website before and I just do not understand how to optimize a website at all haha

```
header{
    background-image: url(banner1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: #FACABC;
    background-position: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

h1, h2, h3, footer{
    text-align: center;
}



h1{
    color: #FACABC;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 500%;
}

h2{
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FACABC;
    color: #987b74;
}

#homelink{
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 135%;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    color: #FACABC;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ion-icon{
    padding-left: 6em;
    font-size: 41px;
    color: #987b74;
}

ion-icon:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body{
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    margin: 0;
    /* test and see if this works wit/without below two things*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: #FACABC;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Nav bar*/
    


.container nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.container nav a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #987b74;
}

.container nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li{
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: sticky;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
}

.container nav ul li:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
}   

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FACABC; /* Background of drop down */
    width: 75%;
    height: 110px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), -1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    top: 74px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{

    font-size: 31px;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    width: 75%;
}

.container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 75%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.container li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a{
    padding: 0;
}

main h2{
    padding-right: 10em;
    padding-left: 10em;
}

main .learn-more{
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #FACABC;
  border: none;
  color: #987b74;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 275px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
}

main .learn-more span{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more span:after{
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more:hover span{
  padding-right: 25px;
}

main .learn-more:hover span:after{
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
} 

.video-trailer{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f8f8f8, #FACABC, #f8f8f8);
}

main ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
}

main h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}

footer{
    color: #987b74;
}

.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

table {
  font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
  color: #987b74;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    body, html{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0.8em 0;
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="wrapper">
    <title>HighItsKy</title>
    <link href="highitsky.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/redrock" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/primer" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">     

<body>
    <header>
        <a id="homelink" href="index.html">
            <h2 id="homelink">HighItsKy</h2>
        </a>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <span class="title"><h1>HighItsKy</h1></span>
        <h2>part time streamer, full time vibe</h2>
        <br><br>
        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/highitsky/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitch"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://discord.gg/M2umXEhkNq" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://youtube.com/highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-tiktok"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></a>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <li style="white-space: nowrap;">About Me
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="AboutMe.html">
                            <li>ABOUT</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Cloves.html">
                            <li>CLOVES</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Socials
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Socials.html">
                            <li>SOCIALS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Contact.html">
                            <li>CONTACT</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <a href="Community.html">
                    <li>Community</li>
                </a>
                <a href="Partnerships.html">
                    <li>Partnerships</li>
                </a>
                <li>Support
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Donate.html">
                            <li>DONATE</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Merch.html">
                            <li>MERCH</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Causes.html">
                            <li>CAUSES</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header"></div>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="backgroundcolor">
        <br><br>
        <h1>High, I'm Ky</h1>
        <br>
            <h2>I started streaming on Twitch in February of 2020, with my streams mainly consisting of Minecraft content! 
            Whether I am dying a lot in Singleplayer or getting scared by creepers, my main focus is maintaining a positive and welcoming 
            community in a not-so-welcoming world. I currently live in Kansas, and I am 19 years old and majoring in Computer Science at FHSU. . . </h2>
            <br>
            <a href="AboutMe.html"><button class="learn-more"><span>LEARN MORE </span></button></a>
            <br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="video-trailer">
            <br><br>
            <h2>My streams consist of a lot of yelling, dying, losing, and sometimes crying, but...</h2>
            <br><br>
            <center>
        <video controls height="64%" width="62%" style='border: 2px solid #FACABC;'>
            <source src="trailer.mp4" srclang="en" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        
            <br><br>
            <h2>what matters is that I get to spend time with the people that I love; my community!</h2>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="backgroundcolor">
            <br><br>
            <h1>High-lights</h1>
            <br><br>
            <hr size="2" color="#987b74">
            <br><br>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HQQ3LfzPrEI" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zNUe4U8ps5k" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sh7yxSijuxI" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <br><br>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PGgvM_9pZok" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S_M8JgzfdW4" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pk0GZE-3EqQ" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br><br>
            <hr size="2" color="#987b74">
            <footer>HighItsKy &copy; 2020 </footer>
        </div>
    </main>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `* { box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5) }` to outline all the elements on the page. There's more than likely something causing the blowout on lower resolutions. A single element that's wider than the viewport. `body {overflow-x: hidden}` could be used to fix this, but it would be better to get to the root of the problem and adjust the element causing the blowout rather than addressing the symptoms.

Comment: @admcfajn oddly enough when i do that, it doesn't end up showing the box shadow at all. I can see it just fine on PC though

Comment: Maybe try using border then? Also, if you're testing on pc using the mobile view of the element inspector to get past the minimum width of the browser might help you replicate the result. The current answer would likely solve the issue but it would be nicer imho to fix the underlying problem. It also can depend on which version of iphone you're using as they support different versions of safari.

Answer (score 1):

You should add width to your body

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    body, html{
        width: 100vw;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0.8em 0;
    }
}
```

```css
header{
    background-image: url(banner1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: #FACABC;
    background-position: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

h1, h2, h3, footer{
    text-align: center;
}



h1{
    color: #FACABC;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 500%;
}

h2{
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FACABC;
    color: #987b74;
}

#homelink{
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 135%;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    color: #FACABC;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ion-icon{
    padding-left: 6em;
    font-size: 41px;
    color: #987b74;
}

ion-icon:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body{
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    margin: 0;
    /* test and see if this works wit/without below two things*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: #FACABC;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Nav bar*/
    


.container nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.container nav a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #987b74;
}

.container nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li{
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: sticky;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
}

.container nav ul li:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
}   

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FACABC; /* Background of drop down */
    width: 75%;
    height: 110px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), -1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    top: 74px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{

    font-size: 31px;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    width: 75%;
}

.container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 75%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.container li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a{
    padding: 0;
}

main h2{
    padding-right: 10em;
    padding-left: 10em;
}

main .learn-more{
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #FACABC;
  border: none;
  color: #987b74;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 275px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
}

main .learn-more span{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more span:after{
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more:hover span{
  padding-right: 25px;
}

main .learn-more:hover span:after{
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
} 

.video-trailer{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f8f8f8, #FACABC, #f8f8f8);
}

main ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
}

main h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}

footer{
    color: #987b74;
}

.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

table {
  font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
  color: #987b74;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    body, html{
        width: 100vw;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0.8em 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="wrapper">
    <title>HighItsKy</title>
    <link href="highitsky.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/redrock" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/primer" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">     

<body>
    <header>
        <a id="homelink" href="index.html">
            <h2 id="homelink">HighItsKy</h2>
        </a>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <span class="title"><h1>HighItsKy</h1></span>
        <h2>part time streamer, full time vibe</h2>
        <br><br>
        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/highitsky/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitch"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://discord.gg/M2umXEhkNq" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://youtube.com/highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-tiktok"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></a>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <li style="white-space: nowrap;">About Me
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="AboutMe.html">
                            <li>ABOUT</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Cloves.html">
                            <li>CLOVES</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Socials
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Socials.html">
                            <li>SOCIALS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Contact.html">
                            <li>CONTACT</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <a href="Community.html">
                    <li>Community</li>
                </a>
                <a href="Partnerships.html">
                    <li>Partnerships</li>
                </a>
                <li>Support
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Donate.html">
                            <li>DONATE</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Merch.html">
                            <li>MERCH</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Causes.html">
                            <li>CAUSES</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header"></div>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="backgroundcolor">
        <br><br>
        <h1>High, I'm Ky</h1>
        <br>
            <h2>I started streaming on Twitch in February of 2020, with my streams mainly consisting of Minecraft content! 
            Whether I am dying a lot in Singleplayer or getting scared by creepers, my main focus is maintaining a positive and welcoming 
            community in a not-so-welcoming world. I currently live in Kansas, and I am 19 years old and majoring in Computer Science at FHSU. . . </h2>
            <br>
            <a href="AboutMe.html"><button class="learn-more"><span>LEARN MORE </span></button></a>
            <br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="video-trailer">
            <br><br>
            <h2>My streams consist of a lot of yelling, dying, losing, and sometimes crying, but...</h2>
            <br><br>
            <center>
        <video controls height="64%" width="62%" style='border: 2px solid #FACABC;'>
            <source src="trailer.mp4" srclang="en" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        
            <br><br>
            <h2>what matters is that I get to spend time with the people that I love; my community!</h2>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="backgroundcolor">
            <br><br>
            <h1>High-lights</h1>
            <br><br>
            <hr size="2" color="#987b74">
            <br><br>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HQQ3LfzPrEI" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zNUe4U8ps5k" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sh7yxSijuxI" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <br><br>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PGgvM_9pZok" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S_M8JgzfdW4" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pk0GZE-3EqQ" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br><br>
            <hr size="2" color="#987b74">
            <footer>HighItsKy &copy; 2020 </footer>
        </div>
    </main>
</html>
```